# Meteor 1.4 updated to Meteor 1.4.1.2 - Connection to MongoDB randomly lost

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

After updating meteor project from Meteor 1.4 to Meteor 1.4.1.2, my project just stops working after some time. No errors are shown either on server or browser side , but my data is not loading.

I suppose that connection to MongoDB is somehow lost. Any ideas what can be problem.

I am working with Windows 7 64-bit OS.

**UPDATE**

Some error occured later:

```
I20161009-13:55:54.584(2)? Exception in setInterval callback: MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed
I20161009-13:55:54.867(2)?     at Object.Future.wait (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\
mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:446:16)
I20161009-13:55:54.867(2)?     at MongoConnection.<anonymous> (packages/meteor/helpers.js:119:1)
I20161009-13:55:54.868(2)?     at MongoConnection.(anonymous function) [as update] (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:771:4
9)
I20161009-13:55:54.869(2)?     at [object Object].update (packages/mongo/collection.js:589:29)
I20161009-13:55:54.869(2)?     at [object Object].Mongo.Collection.(anonymous function) [as update] (packages/aldeed_col
lection2-core/lib/collection2.js:203:1)
I20161009-13:55:54.870(2)?     at AccountsServer.Ap._expireTokens (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1100:14)
I20161009-13:55:54.870(2)?     at packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:1173:14
I20161009-13:55:54.871(2)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20161009-13:55:54.872(2)?     at packages/meteor/timers.js:6:1
I20161009-13:55:54.873(2)?     at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:110:1)
I20161009-13:55:54.873(2)?     - - - - -
I20161009-13:55:54.874(2)?     at Function.MongoError.create (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\1.
5.50\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:29:11)
I20161009-13:55:54.876(2)?     at basicWriteValidations (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\1.5.50\
npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:434:51)
I20161009-13:55:54.877(2)?     at [object Object].Server.update (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo
\1.5.50\npm\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:547:16)
I20161009-13:55:54.878(2)?     at [object Object].Server.update (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo
\1.5.50\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:386:17)
I20161009-13:55:54.879(2)?     at updateDocuments (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\1.5.50\npm\no
de_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:1041:19)
I20161009-13:55:54.880(2)?     at [object Object].Collection.update (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-m
ongo\1.5.50\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:1080:44)
I20161009-13:55:54.882(2)?     at MongoConnection._update (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:560:18)
I20161009-13:55:54.882(2)?     at MongoConnection.<anonymous> (packages/meteor/helpers.js:118:1)
I20161009-13:55:54.883(2)?     at MongoConnection.(anonymous function) [as update] (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:771:4
9)
I20161009-13:55:54.884(2)?     at [object Object].update (packages/mongo/collection.js:589:29)
```

Answer (score 0):

How much time is that? Is it related to the machine sleeping?

Comment: No, it just stops working after few updates of data. It saves data from my form, and then just stops working.

Comment: ok, "just stops working" isn't very helpful. I'm not wanting to be difficult, but you need to explain the things you have done. Have you used meteor mongo to query the database - does that work? Is the app frozen, or does it just not fetch data, or is the problem in saving data?

Comment: Yes I agree with you. I will update question. Problem is that no errors are shown and I am not expirienced developer to figure this out with no errors shown. Robomongo DB managment tool is connecting to database well. But data is not loaded on my app. I am using meteor chef base.as boilerplate.

Comment: see this thread for fixes: https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-app-crash-randomly-throwing-a-mongoerror-server-instance-pool-was-destroyed-error/29610/24

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem... But i am not lost connection to mongo...
My application work on server side but not on client side and there i had a lot errors alert..
So i just install in my work folder this

```
meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
```

and my app started work again. And no anymore blank page on client side.